# How do I find out what process a listening socket is bound to under Solaris 8?

Tags: networking, solaris

On a Solaris 8 server, how do I find out what process is listening on a given port? The Windows implementation of 'netstat' offers the -o and -b switches, which show the owning process ID and name respectively. Is there an equivalent under Solaris?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**`lsof -i`**

Doesn't come installed by default, but you can get Solaris version from http://www.sunfreeware.com/

Comment: Which netstat option provides the owning process under Solaris? I can't seem to find one in the man page? http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/816-1055/6m7gh31ha?a=view

Comment: You're right, thought it's like Linux netstat. But in Solaris -p has different meaning.

Comment: +1 for lsof, definitely worth the trouble of installing.  -i takes arguments of protocol and protocol:port, so you can do something like lsof -i TCP:25 to find out who's listening to 25/tcp (hopefully your mail server!)

Comment: Great answer, i'm never going to struggle with netstat -anp | grep again

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to or can't install lsof, you can also try the command `pfiles`. It prints out all the sockets open by a given process. If you had no other choice, you could iterate over all the PIDs and find the one listening to, say, port 25:

```
PORT=25
for p in $(ps -eo pid)
do
  OUT=$(pfiles $p)
  if [[ "$OUT" =~ port:\ ${PORT} ]]
  then
    echo $p
  fi
done
```